# Two function parameters getting collapsed into one?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I ran into some strange behavior writing a .ps1 script. I wrote a function that takes two parameters, but for some reason the second parameter was always null.

Upon closer inspection, it seems like my two parameters are somehow getting collapsed into the first one.

Given the following script, I would have expected, one line of output showing `...`

```powershell
function Foo($first, $second) {
    echo $first
}

$x = "..."
$y = "why?"

Foo($x, $y)
```

But when I run this script, I get

```powershell
...
why?
```

Is there some PowerShell syntax I don't know about that I'm accidentally (mis-)using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use parens around your arguments and don't use commas to separate arguments.  Invoke your functions just like you would any other PowerShell command - using space separated arguments e.g.:

```
foo $x $y
```

When you put parens around ($x, $y) PowerShell passes that as a single expression/argument, in this case an array containing two items to the first parameter ($x) of your function. You can use `Strict-Mode -Version Latest` to warn you when you do this e.g.:

```powershell
114> function foo($x,$y){}
115> foo(3,4)
116> Set-StrictMode -Version latest
117> foo(3,4)
The function or command was called as if it were a method. Parameters should be separated by  
spaces. For information about parameters, see the about_Parameters Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ foo(3,4)
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StrictModeFunctionCallWithParens
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some PowerShell syntax...that I'm accidentally (mis-)using?

Yes, you are not calling your function properly.  In PowerShell, function calls do **not** use parenthesis or have their arguments separated by commas.

Instead, you would call `Foo` like so:

```powershell
Foo $x $y
```

See a demonstration below:

```powershell
PS > function Foo($first, $second) {
>>     echo $first
>> }
>>
PS > $x = "..."
PS > $y = "why?"
PS > Foo $x $y
...
PS >
PS > function Foo($first, $second) {
>>     echo "$first and $second"
>> }
>>
PS > Foo $x $y
... and why?
PS >
```

---

In case you are wondering, your current code has PowerShell interpreting `($x, $y)` as a single argument to `Foo`: a two-item array.  Thus, it assigns this array to `$first` and `$null` to `$second`:

```powershell
PS > function Foo($first, $second) {
>>     echo "Type of `$first: $($first.Gettype())"
>>     echo "`$second is `$null: $($second -eq $null)"
>> }
>>
PS > $x = "..."
PS > $y = "why?"
PS > Foo($x, $y)
Type of $first: System.Object[]
$second is $null: True    
PS >
```

Comment: Sorry about that unintended edit.  I hate how SO randomly seems to reorder the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The "," is used differently in powershell than in other programming languages. Here it is the array constructor.

```powershell
(1,2,3).GetType()       # System.Object[]
(,'element').GetType()  # System.Object[]
```

Because you havent specified a datatype on your parameters the powershell assumes it is dealing with plain old System.Objects (the superclass of all classes). It then takes the array and assigns it to the first input parameter because it is the only one in this line. It can do that because an array is, by extension, also a System.Object.

Also, the old synthax for defining functions is not recommended anymore:

```powershell
function foo ( $first, $second ) {}
```

When writing this, the powershell interpreter would internally convert this into an advanced function:

```powershell
function foo {
   PARAM( 
       [Parameter(Position=1)]
       [object]$first,
       [Parameter(Position=2)]
       [object]$second
   )
   BEGIN { <# Do stuff here #> }
   PROCESS { <# Do stuff here #> }
   END { <# Do stuff here #> } 
}

foo -first 'first' -second 'second'
foo 'first' 'second'
```

Causing unneeded overhead.
I hope that clears it up a little :)